# Running Archangle 3.4.2 Freenix server for WoW in linux?

Tags: server, virtualbox, wine, games

Has anyone got the Archangle 3.4.2 Freenix server to run in Wine or in Ubuntu on the back of a APl. I've tried a few times and can't find anything on it at [wow-one.com](http://wow-one.com) or on the [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org).

I have been looking off and on for a few months and no ones popped a QA and I've yet to find info. I've been keeping windows around special for the WoW server since I'm not a pay to play kinda guy. It's been a few weeks since I've messed with it.

Since windows 10 and all the security holes and crap-ware scare me to much I was setting up my GPC with ubuntu and going to run VBox so I can feel safer. It's crazy how much stuff they want to know about you... They are probably worse then google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and since all the install guides are for battle.net I made one for the Freenix server and posted it on the Freenix forum and Ubuntuforums all so.

> 1.) Go to the link below in a new tab and follow the download instructions. >Instead of using bitTorrent Ubuntu has a built in application called Transmission bitTorrent Client you can use to download the torrent file be >for opening it with archive manager and extracting it to the desired >location.
>
> http://www.wow-one.com/forum/topic/139-243-tbc-client-download-and-install/
>
> > 2. Downloading the wow 2.4.3 client:
> >
> > > > 2.4.3 WoW No-Install (full client):
> > > >         Mirror1: http://goo.gl/cXOLyy
> >
> > 3. Installing the wow 2.4.3 client:
> >
> > > > > Simply download & extract tbc, with Winrar.
> >
> > 4. Set your realmlist
> >
> > > > Realmlist.wtf is a text File that tells your WoW game client which server (realm) to connect to.
> > > >
> > > > Realmlist.wtf is located in your world of Warcraft directory. To change the server (realm) you want to connect to open the realmlist.wtf file, and replace its content with:
> > > >
> > > > For Archangel:
> > > >
> > > > set realmlist vanillafeenix.servegame.org
> >
> > 5. Create your Feenix game account
> >
> > > > Create your 2.4.3 game account on our vanilla wow website
> > > >         Click to sign up for your feenix gameaccount on the Vanilla wow realm website
> >
> > 6.) After the Realmlist.wtf file is configured and you have a freenix account. You'll need to install wine to run Burning Crusade.
> >
> > 7.) After wine is installed open up Configure Wine in your applications list. Under the Application tab select Add application and go to the directory with the Freenix 2.4.3 client folder. Inside the folder directory select Wow.exe and add it to the Applications list for wine. Then select your desired windows version and then Apply and Okay.
> >
> > 8.) In Ubuntu go to the directory you have the Freenix 2.4.3 client folder in and right click and select open with Wine Windows Program Loader. Then open the Wow.exe program to run the game.
> >
> > 9.) After signing in to the WoW login it will prompt you to select a server if it did not find the Archangle server by default. You will need to select Development and then PvP be for selecting Search Realmlist. This should connect you dirrectly to the Archangle game server or offer you a selection of the freenix servers to pick from that you configured your Realmlist.wtf file for. After selecting your realm you may create your character and start playing WoW.